# How do I remove $y$ from $xy$ in $y=xy-2x$?

Tags: inverse-function

I got an inverse function $y=xy-2x$. 
But how do I remove $y$ from $xy$?

Comment: Regardless of the answers you get here, do not call yourself stupid.  Calling yourself names is a signal of defeat.  Aside from not being nice to yourself, having some mental toughness or stick-to-it-ness (aka grit) is hugely important for math and whatever else you pursue.  “We are what we pretend to be, so we must be careful about what we pretend to be." - Kurt Vonnegut

Comment: Thank you  @JavaMan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write  $$y-xy=-2x$$ and $$y(1-x)=-2x$$ so $$y=\frac{-2x}{1-x}$$ for $x\ne 1$

Comment: Thanks @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner!

Comment: What if $x$ ≠ 2?

Comment: This can be then you divide not by $0$

Comment: So just don't divide it by $0$ right?

Comment: Only in the case of $x=1$

Comment: So you mean that when $x=1$ you don't divide by $0$ but you do in the other cases?

Comment: Only in the case when $x=1$ you divide by $0$ and in no other case

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for that!

Comment: @Kakeru: if this answer really helped you, you might consider to accept it. :)